# area of quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

Let ABCD be a rectangle and AD and BC its diagonals.Let K be the point of intersection of the diagonals and  P be the midpoint of  AB.CP and DP intersect the diagonals at  E ,F respectively.How do we find the area of PEKF if the area of ABCD is 20?I tried to eliminate the area of other parts and then subtract from the total,but there is always somekind of intersection.I also tried to use the fact that triangle PCD is half the area of the total rectangle.I even divided the rectangle into four smaller rectangles and then calculate each part separately.Some kind of hint will be appreciated.

Comment: I have made a rough approximation of 2.33 but not sure if it is correct.

Comment: $PCD$ is half of the area of which rectangle?

Comment: @Ric ped,The rectangle ABCD of course.

Comment: Ah, it's a rectangle so :)

Comment: @Ric Ped,Ah I was stupid.How could I have forgotten to mention that?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The yellow part is $\dfrac{3}{4}$ of the whole rectangle and for the green part, I present [THIS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404956/area-of-intersecting-part-of-triangles/404982#404982) to you as a hint.

Comment: Ah,that old problem of mine.Yes,I think I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

$\hspace{4.6cm}$[image]

**Hint:** $\triangle KFP$ is similar to $\triangle BFD$ and $|KP|=\frac12|BD|$. . Furthermore, $|BP|=\frac12|BA|$